# Why Allow Implicit Flow option by default checked in app registration at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

What is the use of "Allow Implicit Flow" option in Microsoft App Regsitration for MSAL.

While adding platform , above option is default checked-in. What happens if uncheck Allow Implicit Flow option.

Comment: refer here: http://anthonygiretti.com/tag/implicit-flow/

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if uncheck Allow Implicit Flow option.

If uncheck Allow Implicit Flow option, when you send an OpenID Connect authorization request to get an id_token from the v2.0 endpoint, an unsupported_response error will be returned: `The provided value for the input parameter 'response_type' is not allowed for this client. Expected value is 'code'`.

In the Application Registration Portal, the Allow Implicit Flow option enables the OpenID Connect hybrid and implicit flows. The hybrid flow enables the app to receive both sign-in info (the id token) and artifacts that the app uses to obtain an access token. The hybrid flow is the default flow used by the OWIN OpenID Connect middleware. For single page apps (SPA), the implicit flow enables the app to receive sign-in info and the access token.

For this, you could also see clearly in the app registration(preview):
[image]
For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2).